# MoreNavigationController images disappearing on select

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController which has been created programatically, which has 6 tabs. As such the MoreNavigationController is automatically created to take care of having more than 5 tabs. Everything looks fine when the MoreNavigationController is displayed, but when I select one of these rows to push the view controller on to the stack, the cell image (tab bar image) disappears. When I pop that view controller, the image remains hidden until the pop animation is completed, at which point the image suddenly appears again.

This is fairly old code and I wouldn't do it this way these days, but everything works except for this last little thing so I'm pretty hesitant to rip out all the code and do it another way. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

An example of creating one of the tab bar view controllers:

```
InfoViewController* infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
infoViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"90-life-buoy.png"];
infoViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"More Info";
infoViewController.title = @"More Info";
UINavigationController* infoNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];
[infoViewController release];
```

Creating the tab bar:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:outdoorsNavController, peopleNavController, citiesNavController, landscapesNavController, infoNavController, basicsNavController, nil];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

EDIT: Doesn't seem to make any difference whether I use retina (@2x) images or not.

Comment: Are you saying that when you click on a tab bar item, the item image dissappears until you select another tab bar item?

Comment: No, this only occurs in the MoreNavigationController. This is a tableView which is automatically created when there are more than 5 tabs in a UITabBarController. The tableview uses the UITabBarItem title and image for the extra tabs to create the table cells. When I select one of these rows, the cell image, which is actually the tabBarItem image, disappears as the associated view controller is being pushed into view. This causes an ugly looking flash, especially as the view controller is popped as the image only re-appears once the controller is fully popped.

Comment: Can't see if you're following Apple's recommendation from your code above: **Do not add the object stored in this property to your tab bar interface manually. The More controller is displayed automatically by the tab bar controller as it is needed. You must also not look for the More navigation controller in the array of view controllers stored in the viewControllers property. The tab bar controller does not include the More navigation controller in that array of objects.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're wrapping your `InfoViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

When you click on the table row in `MoreNavigationController`, the controller uses the `tabBarItem` in `UINavigationController` while it does its transition. Because this is nil (in your code), the image in `MoreNavigationController` disappears. When the transition finally finishes, `MoreNavigationController` picks up the `tabBarItem` in `InfoViewController`

Try this:

```
InfoViewController* infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
infoViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"90-life-buoy.png"];
infoViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"More Info";
infoViewController.title = @"More Info";
UINavigationController* infoNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];
//Set the tabBarItem for UINavigationController
infoNavController.tabBarItem = infoViewController.tabBarItem
[infoViewController release];
```

Here's a video reproducing and fixing the issue:
Item 7 has an empty `tabBarItem.image` while Item 6 has `tabBarItem.image` set
[image]

Comment: You are awesome, Thank you! I solved this in my app by setting the `self.title = rootViewController.title;` and `self.tabBarItem = rootViewController.tabBarItem;` in my custom UINavigationController subclass

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but have you tried setting the `NavigationCotroller's` `.tabBarItem`?

Comment: Nice idea, but no luck I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but on the top of my head here are some suggestions (The More Tab Bar item shouldn't disappear at all times, that is created automatically)

1. Have you tried subclassing your `UINavigationController` that is being used for the MoreController's place and set its tab bar items properties there, therefore making sure you have control over its lifetime ?
2. Subclass your `UIViewController`'s that you wish to push onto the navigation stack and have them use the same tab bar item ?
3. Mimic the default functionality, create your own `UITableViewController` to act as the More Controller, and at each tap of the rows, do what you want, also in a custom way.

PS: Try setting images name without the .png extension. This way you will automatically load the @2x resource as well. Eg: [UIImage imageNamed:@"90-life-buoy"]

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1)