# moreNavigationController not displaying image for an instant

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar that is working properly but when I add more elements and the more button appears it is showing a strange behavior.

If I select one item and then come back by pressing again the "more" button, the selected item does not show the image for a few seconds and then is shown again.

I have created the the UITabBar programmatically and I have change the UITableView of the moreNavigationController colors programmatically to.

If I remove the personalization of the moreNavigationController the behavior is there to.

My first guess was the tint color of the UITabBar (is white) but I change it to red and the behavior is the same.

Then I though it was the image but the unselected image is grey and the selected image is blue.

**This is the code I use to create the UITabBar:**

```
- (void)createTabBar
{
    tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cCustomTabController"];
    dValue = [dConfiguration objectForKey:@"Buttons"];
    NSMutableArray  *aControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString* sProperty in dValue) {
        NSString* d = @"Details";
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [_reachabilityInfo currentReachabilityStatus];
        NSData *itemData = Nil;
        if (internetStatus != NotReachable)
            itemData = [util getSpecificJsonData:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Item"]];
        if(itemData != nil){
            UIStoryboard *aStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            UIViewController *vcCustom = [aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[util getControllerName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ViewController"]]];
            [vcCustom setValue:itemData forKey:@"JsonData"];
            [vcCustom setValue:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Item"] forKey:@"Item"];
            [vcCustom setValue:d forKey:@"Details"];
            [util saveJSON:itemData withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Item"],[CommonsUtils getCommonUtil].getAppLanguage]];
            [[vcCustom navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
            vcCustom.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = Nil;
            vcCustom.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
            UIImage *imageBtn = [self changeImageSize:[UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]]] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
            UIImage *imageBtnPress = [self changeImageSize:[UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageHeighlighted"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetinaHeighlighted"]]] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
            UITabBarItem *tab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"] image:imageBtn selectedImage:imageBtnPress];
            UIImage * iSelected = imageBtnPress;
            iSelected = [iSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            [tab setSelectedImage:iSelected];
            tab.tag = i;
            if([[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"] isEqualToString:@"Notificaciones"])
                tab.badgeValue=[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Badge"];
            [vcCustom setTabBarItem:tab];
            [vcCustom setTitle:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"]];
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[cCustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcCustom];
            navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = NAVBAR_TINTCOLOR;
            UIColor *uicText = NAVBAR_TEXTCOLOR;
            navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:uicText forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
            [aControllers insertObject:navigationController atIndex:i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    tabController.delegate = self;
    tabController.viewControllers = aControllers;
    tabController.tabBar.tintColor = TABBAR_TINTCOLOR;
    UIColor *uicTabBar = TABBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:uicTabBar];

    tabController.customizableViewControllers = @[];
    tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = NAVBAR_TINTCOLOR;
    UIColor *uicText = NAVBAR_TEXTCOLOR;
    tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = NAVBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:uicText forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
}
```

**And this is how I personalize the UITableView of the moreNavigationController:**

```
UITableView *tView = (UITableView*)tabController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
if ([[tView subviews] count]) {
    for (UITableViewCell *cCell in [tView visibleCells]) {
        cCell.textLabel.textColor = TABLECELL_TEXT_COLOR;
        cCell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = TABLECELL_TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHTED;
        cCell.contentView.backgroundColor = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
        cCell.backgroundColor = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
        UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        UIColor *uicCell = TABLECELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR_SELECTED
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:uicCell];
        [cCell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
    }
}
```

**In this image you can see what is happening:**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw here:

[MoreNavigationController images disappearing on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748342/morenavigationcontroller-images-disappearing-on-select)

I have added this line to my code:

```
navigationController.tabBarItem = vcCustom.tabBarItem;
```

Thanks for the help.